# shared methods and properties in Backbone.js?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I was reviewing of the code of an application. I cam across the follwing code which I am unable to understand comprehensively.

```
 define(['av'], function (av) {
     av.Application.BaseView = function (options) {
      //add non-shared methods/properties here --------------------- 1)

    };
    _.extend(av.Application.BaseView.prototype, Backbone.View.prototype, {
      // add shared methods/properties here ------------------------ 2)
    });
   av.Application.BaseView.extend = Backbone.View.extend;

});
```

Can anybody  why the methods/properties added after comment no 1 are non-shared and after comment no 2 are shared among their child instances?

Comment: Are you familiar with `prototype` in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first block of code defines a constructor function, which is called every time you `new` up a view. In that function you can create public properties with the syntax:

```
this.foo = "bar";
```

This initialization code runs every time a view is initialized, and it attaches the properties to the *instance* of the view. Instance properties are not shared.

The second block of code extends the constructor function's prototype, first with all the properties of `Backbone.View`, and then with the properties defined in the block. Prototype properties are shared between all instances of the function, or "class", if you wish.

What that code essentially does is create a new function, and then enhance it with `Backbone.View`'s properties. Because the `Backbone.View`'s own constructor function is never called (at least in the code you posted), it means that this class wouldn't quite work like a normal Backbone View. For instance a `model` or `id` property passed to a constructor would not be copied to the instance automatically, as they normally would:

```
var view = new av.Application.BaseView({model:model});
console.log(view.model); //-> undefined
```

Backbone also supports overriding the constructor function more cleanly by setting a `constructor` attribute in the class definition:

```
av.Application.BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({

    //override the constructor function
    constructor: function(options) {

        //this property is not shared between instances
        this.foo = 'bar';

        //call Backbone's own constructor, so we get all the default behavior
        Backbone.View.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    //this property is attached to the prototype, and is shared
    baz: 'qux'
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot your detail answer helped me to understand.